# How many constructors will I need in a Java Application?

Tags: java, constructor

So, if I have a `public class` named 'X', and it has 5 variables. Do I have to code a constructor for every variable combinationw? My teach doesn't clarify this for me, but I think that's not necessary because the application maybe will be too heavy (or not?), but otherwise this could increase the Application flexibility.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Adding constructors does not make an application heavy, just less readable and you waste time when you add constructors that nobody ever uses. You can also set variables after an object is constructed through setter methods, and it's actually quite common that a variable is not set by the constructor but only later. Constructor is for variables that must be set at construction time or often for convenience.

Comment: You do not need to provide any constructor, as Java compiler will create one for you. See `default construction` in Java for more info. See also [Builder Pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern) to construct complex objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.

Five instance variables isn't a large amount from what I've seen, so a constructor that takes `5` parameters wouldn't be the worst thing in the world.  As you know, Java allows you to have multiple constructors in a single class, so you could essentially overload the constructor that takes `5` parameters with one that provides default values for some of the parameters, such as:

```
public Test(int a, int b, String c, long d, float e) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.e = e;
}

public Test(int a, int b) {
    this(a, b, "Test", 0L, 3.14F);
}
```

You could also look into the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) if you want to only initialize *some* of the instance variables rather than all of them when instantiating the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide no public constructor if you want.

With Java, you can use multiple constructors to achieve proper behaviour of object initialisation. Number of them results from possible real scenarios. If e.g. last two parameters are optional or can be estimated from previous params, provide such a constructor.

You can also use some tricks with this() as follows:

```
public class Test {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
    private int d;

    public Test(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

    public Test(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = 0;
        this.d = 0;

        // or: this(a, b, 0, 0);
    }

    public Test() {
        this(5, 1, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When defining a constructor I ask myself which are the minimum pieces of information that I need in order to have a working instance of the class. For example, the class java.io.File has 4 constructor and they all take a path to the file. There is no empty constructor because it doesn't make sense to have a File with no path or file system location.

Now for the class Bike, you might want to define an empty contructor that initialise the instance with a standard bike attributes: 2 wheels, etc. And then have setters to customise if needed.